# Ayuda para exportar estos datos

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba

Hola les deseo un buen día, la cosa es esta...

Actualmente tengo este código para un botón

```
Private Sub btnfiltrar_Click()
On Error GoTo ErroresIf 
Me.txtfiltro.Value = "" Or Me.txtfiltro.Value = " " Then
Me.ltbdatos.Clear
Else
Me.ltbdatos.Clear
j = 1
Set BD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APU")
Filas = BD.Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To Filas
    If LCase(BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.txtfiltro.Value) & "*" Then
        Me.ltbdatos.AddItem BD.Cells(i, j)
        Me.ltbdatos.List(Me.ltbdatos.ListCount - 1, 1) = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2)
        Me.ltbdatos.List(Me.ltbdatos.ListCount - 1, 2) = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 15)
    Else
    End If
Next i
End If
Exit Sub
Errores:
MsgBox "No existe.", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

[image: Este es el formulario donde esta el botón cuyo código adjunte]

Con ese código me traigo los datos de la columna A, C y P hasta un ListBox; Pero yo solo necesito que me traigan los datos de las columnas C y P, como debo modificar ese código para lograr lo que deseo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la línea que se lleva el valor de la columna A es `Me.ltbdatos.AddItem BD.Cells(i, j`). Pero por lo que veo, tu Listbox tiene 3 columnas

> (Cod, Nombre, Valor Total).

Tendrías que modificar tu listbox para que solamente sean dos columnas, y entonces modificar el código para que te rellene ambas columnas tal que así:

```
Me.ltbdatos.AddItem  = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2)
Me.ltbdatos.List(Me.ltbdatos.ListCount - 1, 1) = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 15)
```

Otra opción, aunque **no garantizo que vaya a funcionar, y además lo veo menos profesional y sucio**, pero te puede ayudar a salir del paso, sería intentar engañar al Listbox y que rellene la columna Cod con valores en blanco. Algo así como:

```
Me.ltbdatos.AddItem " "
Me.ltbdatos.List(Me.ltbdatos.ListCount - 1, 1) = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2)
Me.ltbdatos.List(Me.ltbdatos.ListCount - 1, 2) = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 15)
```

Pero **mi recomendación profesional es que hagas lo primero que he dicho**. Tal y como está diseñado tu Listbox ¿ Por qué querrías no enseñar el valor de la columna A? No termino de verle la utilidad a quitarlo. ¿Te estorba de alguna manera?

Comment: Gracias, el código me funciono bien pero ahora cuando ajusto las columnas no me muestra el valor

Asi lo tenia antes
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ltbdatos
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .ColumnWidths = "60 pt; 170 pt; 71 pt"
End With
End Sub

Y ahora lo he colocado asi

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ltbdatos
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "170 pt; 71 pt"
End With
End Sub


Y solo me muestra el nombre, pero si lo dejo con las 3 columna me muestra el nombre y el precio, como corrijo eso?

Comment: ¿Cuál de los dos códigos usaste? ¿El bueno, rediseñando el Listbox a 2 columnas? ¿O el sucio y poco profesional? Necesito saber eso para darte la respuesta correcta. En otras palabras. ¿Usaste el primer código o el segundo código? Supongo que el segundo...

Comment: El bueno, rediseñando el Listbox a 2 columnas

Comment: Vale, ¿cual es el valor de la propiedad `tbldatos.rowsource` cuando sale tu lisbox? ¿Abarca la columna A?

Comment: Si no, antes de `For i = 2 To Filas` prueba a añadir `Me.ltbdatos.RowSource = ""`

Comment: No tenia agregada la propiedad Me.ltbdatos.RowSource = "", ya la coloque  y ahora puedo visualizar los valores, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te sirviera :)