# Ayuda para colocar una condición a este código

Tags: excel, vba

He estado trabajando con este código

```
Private Sub btnfiltrar_Click()
On Error GoTo Errores
If Me.txtfiltro.Value = "" Or Me.txtfiltro.Value = " " Then
    Me.ltbdatos.Clear
Else
    Me.ltbdatos.Clear
    j = 1
    Set BD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APU")
    Filas = BD.Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Me.ltbdatos.RowSource = ""
    For i = 2 To Filas
        If LCase(BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.txtfiltro.Value) & "*" Then
            Me.ltbdatos.AddItem BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2)
            Me.ltbdatos.List(Me.ltbdatos.ListCount - 1, 1) = BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 15)
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End If
Exit Sub
Errores:
MsgBox "No existe.", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Yo tengo un pequeño BuscarV que cuando el usuario coloque una palabra clave y le de buscar, ese código ira a una base de datos y le traerá todos los datos que coincidan. El problema es que quiero limitar un poco mas esa búsqueda y para hacerlo necesito de una condicional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el cuadro de búsqueda, en cuanto el usuario coloque la palabra clave y le de click al botón "Filtrar" el programa se ira a la siguiente base de datos y traerá todos los datos que coincidan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito que haga la condicional es que solo me traiga los valores que están en rojo, pero no se como hacerla, he pensado en usar la columna "Columna 1" como filtro (Si el valor = 1 que me lo traiga, si no, que pase al siguiente valor)

Comment: Bienvenida Stefa. Solamente una aclaración. Entiendo que buscas por la Columna CÓDIGO. Es decir, en este caso, si introducimos el valor 40110, quieres que te devuelva todo lo remarcado en rojo, ya que el código de cada una de esas filas empieza por 40110. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Actualmente se busca por la columna "DESCRIPCIÓN", el problema es que como lo dices solo necesito que me devuelva los valores en rojo, ya que si el usuario busca algo como "Tubería" podrán salir valores en rojo y negro. Espero a ver sido clara

Comment: Para que te muestre todos los valores en rojo según DESCRIPCIÓN, necesitas un texto común a todos. Si, por ejemplo, pongo la palabra OFICINAS, solamente mostraría "Oficinas provisionales" y "Dotación Oficinas". Lo digo porque no encuentro ahora mismo un texto común a todos los registros que quieres mostrar. ¿Cual sería el término común?

Comment: No es necesario un texto en común, hay un patron fácil de identificar para la columna `[Código]` puede usar la función `LEN` en un `IF`. Algo como `If Len(Cells(i, j)) = 7 Then ...` "Reemplazar `i`, `j` con su correspondiente coordenada para la columna [Código]"

Comment: Elier. No hay términos en común, esa es solo una pequeña parte de la base de datos, también hay tuberías de muchos tipos, cementos, implemento y muchas cosas mas.

virtualdvid, no entiendo como usar el código que me dices jejejeje soy muy nueva en esto

Comment: @stefazapata Hay otro usuario que ha posteado la misma tabla que tú. De hecho, vuestro código es de una modificación que pidió aquí. Prueba a ver si te puede ayudar él, porque debe ser compañero de trabajo tuyo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140524/ayuda-para-exportar-estos-datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede resolverse usando el campo `[Código]` sin necesidad de crear una columna adicional. Los que están resaltados en rojo se ve que son `7` caracteres por código `4011001` entonces se puede usar la función `LEN` que devuelve el numero de caracteres y anidarla dentro del `IF` que ya contiene el código:

```
If LCase(BD.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 2).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.txtfiltro.Value) & "*" And Len(DB.Cells(i, j).Value) = 7 Then
```

Comment: Cuando modifico la linea de código y la coloco tal cual me muestras y hago una búsqueda por ejemplo "STC" me sale un mensaje diciendo "No existe" (ese mensaje yo lo agregue para que saliera cuando no se encuentre lo que el usuario busca), pero ese "STC" si existe en la base de datos

Comment: En linea tienes que adaptar la parte de `Cell(i, j)` de la formula `Len` según `j` que es el número de columna donde se encuentra el campo `[Código]`. por otra parte el `If`analiza dos condiciones y ambas tienen que ser verdaderas. El problema puede estar en la `[Columna1]` que se adiciono que no pertenece a la base original. Esto hace que busque "STC" en la columna equivocada.

Comment: Tonta de mi, no me fije en ese detalle, muchas gracias en verdad